# Fastest way of getting latest commit timestamp of each file in a directory

Tags: git

I need to get the latest commit date for all files in a folder in a Git repository.

I have been using the following process on each file in the directory:

```
git -C c:\my\path\to\git\project log -1 --format=%cd --date=iso -- path/to/myfile.txt
```

This is extremely slow because there are 1000+ files in this folder.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Heehee, I wanted to say for the [previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62951521/7976758) it's slow. But decided to wait. Now the wait is over. :-)

Comment: What does "extremely slow" actually mean?

Comment: getting the timestamps of 10 files on my system takes about 13 seconds. this may be due to virus scanners and such

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first produce the files list with `ls-files` then send that to `git log` through `xargs` :

```
git ls-files path/to/dir | xargs -n 1 git log -1 --format=%cd --date=iso --
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's call what you are doing *from files, get revisions* but you might want to switch to *from revisions, get files*. If you do `git log --name-only` of that directory, you will get what files changed on each revision... as files show up, you know when is the last time they were modified.... you will need a list to know what files are still _ missing_ to know if you need to dig deeper.... but it will be faster, for sure.

Comment: I wrote [a Python script](https://git.phdru.name/?p=git-scripts.git;a=blob;f=set-commit-date.py) and regularly use it and update it myself.