# Faster way to get the timestamp of latest comitted file in a set of git files?

Tags: bash, git

I have seen [Fastest way of getting latest commit timestamp of each file in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62996833/fastest-way-of-getting-latest-commit-timestamp-of-each-file-in-a-directory) - and it is pretty much almost the same question in general, except I cannot tell how I could apply the solutions there in my case. So I'll try posting my case, with hopefully a bit more info.

So, I want to get the time of the commit of the latest/newest committed file in a set of git files. For the set, I use, say `git ls-files -z -- . ':!:*.md' ':!:*.bin'`; I can tell this command is fast, because I've earlier used it as a replacement for something else, and it brought a significant speed up on my system, which is MINGW64 `bash` under Windows 10.

Just counting the result lines of the above set takes some 200 ms, which is very nice:

```
$ git ls-files -z -- . ':!:*.md' ':!:*.bin' | xargs -0 printf "%s\n" | wc -l
261

real    0m0.201s
user    0m0.139s
sys     0m0.015s
```

However, I want this set with the latest commit Unix timestamp, sorted by newest, and getting the newest committed timestamp; now on my system, that takes 30+ seconds for the same set of files!!!:

```
$ git ls-files -z -- . ':!:*.md' ':!:*.bin' | xargs -0 -n 1 git log -1 --format=%ct --name-only | paste -d " "  - - -  | sort -r | head -1
1697665319  myfile1.txt

real    0m30.201s
user    0m6.991s
sys     0m20.395s
```

Well, half a minute is already unacceptable for me for this (sorting 261 result lines)...

The problem is, that git log can only take a single file as argument, not multiple files; ergo, therefore 261 instances of `git log` must be spawned, instead of one instance with 261 arguments. Furthermore, the output is printed in three lines per `git log` call, so I have to use `paste` to concatenate in single line; those results look like

```
git ls-files -z -- . ':!:*.md' ':!:*.bin' | xargs -0 -n 1 git log -1 --format=%ct --name-only | paste -d " "  - - -  | sort -r 

1697665319  myfile1.txt
1697665319  myfile2.txt
1697665319  myfile3.txt
1697665319  myfile4.txt
1697665319  CMakeLists.txt
1697662735  myfile5.txt
1697662735  myfile6.txt
...

real    0m27.860s
user    0m6.326s
sys     0m20.908s
```

... which makes sense, if multiple files are part of the same commit.

So, can I somehow obtain the commit timestamp of the latest commited file in a set of get-tracked files faster (I'd like to wait at most a second or two for this kind of complexity, not half a minute)?

Comment: I don't think there is a ready-made Git tool that does what you need. You would have to create your own script. If I were to do it, I would write a perl|python|whatever script that parses the output of a variant of `git log --name-status --diff-filter=d --no-renames --format=%ct HEAD -- file...`, accumulating timestamps and file names as it goes.

Comment: a perl one liner which may format log output `perl -0777ne 'for(split/^(?=\d)/m){($t,$x,@a)=split/\n/;$h{s/^.\t//r}||=$t for@a};print"$h{$_} $_\n" for sort keys%h'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this :

```
git log --name-only --format="%ct" -- . ':!:*.md' ':!:*.bin' | awk '/^[0-9]+$/{t=$1}/^[^0-9]/{print t,$0}' | sort -r | head -1
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `head -1`? I read the Q such that the date of the most recent change for each file is wanted.

Comment: Awesome, thanks - tried this on my set as used in OP; first run (without `head -1`) "real 0m4.141s", second run (with `head -1`) "real 0m0.284s"; third run (without `head -1`) "0m0.338s" - that I can live with! @j6t - it's true that I want the date of most recent change for each file, but I wanted that set so I can sort it and ultimately retrieve the newest (hence the `head -1`)